# Creating a model in Django whose field has multiple other fields inside it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm quite new to Django and would like to clear a noob doubt.
Say I have a post request to a model `Scans` in django.

The json data for the same looks like

> [{"id":1, "results":{"low": 3, "medium": 6, "high": 7}, "machine": "Windows", "report": "yes"]

How should the model look like? I can't figure out what field type I should give to `results`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField). 
Your model should look like that.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Scans(models.Model):
    machine = models.CharField(...)
    results = JSONField(default=dict)
```

P.S. You need to configure your database(in this case PostgreSQL)

P.S.S If you dont want to use PostgreSQL here is JSONFIeld for [MySQL](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create two models `Scans` and `Results` and create a relationship between them as follows

```
class Scans(models.Model):
    machine = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    # assuming that report is by default false
    report = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    results = models.ForeignKey(Results, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 


class Results(models.Model):
    low = models.IntegerField()
    medium = models.IntegerField()
    high = models.IntegerField()
```